# difference between vector and thread safe arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, vector

What is the difference between vector & Thread safe arraylist in Java. Vector is synchronized and arraylist is not. But if we make the arrayist thread safe then will it be same like vector ? One difference is that vector grows by 100% where as arraylist grows by 50%. Any difference related to performance or other factor ?

Comment: Please label with the _language_ you are using.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated and forget Vector unless you are dealing with legacy code.

Comment: The difference is that `Vector` has been dead for, like, 20 years now.  Pretend you've never heard of it.  It's _never_ the right thing to use.  In the worst case, use `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are really old, I really would never recommend using them. As for thread-safe alternatives to ArrayList you should take a look at [Google Guava (Immutable Collections Explained)](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained)

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` gives better performance as it is non-synchronized. `Vector` operations gives poor performance as they are thread-safe, the thread which works on `Vector` gets a lock on it which makes other thread wait till the lock is released.

Read [this](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/difference-between-arraylist-and-vector-in-java/) for more info.

Comment: It would be more correct to say that `Vector` operations are *synchronized.* They aren't thread-safe in the presence of iterators, for example, without external synchronization.